# X Y (Scatter) graph in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scatter-plot

[image]I am trying to create a **XY scatter graph** in ***VB.NET***

Is There another style that I am needing to use to get the closest representation to that of Excel X Y (Scatter)? When  I use the same information in VB.NET Vs. Excel I get two seperate results. I am assuming that I am not truly using VB.NET Scatter graph. https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/chart/chart-types?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#scatter-chart shows that using scatter plot is possible. Issue is when I try `Dim series As New ChartSeries ("Series Name", ChartSeriesType.Scatter)` It gives me error codes.

```
Hourly_Chart.Title.Add("CRS Weekly") 'Name of chart
Hourly_Chart.chartAreas.Clear()
Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas.Add("Default") 'Not Sure what this does
With Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas("Default") 'Not Sure what this does
    Hourly_Chart.Series.Clear() 'Not Sure what this does
End With

With Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
    .Title = "Date"
    .Islogarithmic = False
End With

With Hourly_Chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY
    .Title = "Counts"
    .IsLogarithmic = True
End With

Hourly_Chart.Series.Add("CR1")
Hourly_Chart.series("CR1").Color = Color.Green
Hourly_Chart.Series("CR1").ChartType = .DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point
For i1 As Integer = 1 To CountsOfCR1Rows
    Dim y1 as Single
    Dim x1 As String
    x1 = One01_a2Darray(i1,1).Replace("T", " ")
    y1 = One01_a2Darray(i1,44)
    If y1 = 0 Then y1 = 1
    Hourly_Chart.Series("CR1").Points.AddXY(x1,y1)
Next
```

Comment: If you add screengrabs of what you have and what you want then you can point out the differences that you would like to resolve.

Comment: I can the photos a poor quality due to the computer I am writing code on does not have internet nor access to USB drive

Comment: Can it write to CD-RW discs? Or floppy disks? Or at least you could post separate images for each one - as they are, I cannot quite see the details I guess I need to see. As I mentioned before, you could add annotations (even freehand red circles) to the images to direct us to the exact parts we need to pay attention to. Also, please use PNG files to avoid JPEG degradation of the images as far as possible.

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/chart/chart-types?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#scatter-chart                          This link answers allot of questions. The problem is that it says to use                                 Dim series As New ChartSeries ("Series Name", ChartSeriesType.Scatter)                         My VB.Net wont allow me to use this.  I think it is due to having a older version of vb.net The computer I use is a "newer" but due to work restrictions I am limited on how to get information from it.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using the SyncFusion ChartControl, not a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting control? They are two very different things.

Comment: It seems that the policies in your workplace are restricting your ability to work :( Can you write the code on a computer with internet access, then when it is working copy it to the work computer? You should raise the issue with your manager—they are there to make sure you are supplied with the resources to enable you to do your work.

Comment: Are scatter plot options on newer versions of VB.net? I have the ability to use bubble.

Comment: Ill edit my post again and I will type out what I have now

Comment: You are not telling us what you have. You are not telling us what you want it to become. Please think about how you can present the problem that you have to us.

Comment: I have a line graph in VB.Net I am trying to make a scatter graph. The code I listed brings up my graph as a point or line graph. I cannot find where to change it to a scatter plot chart.

Comment: Sorry, but to me it looks like the two charts are showing the same data. Could you use a small set of data with just one series so that we can see the difference? I can see there is a gap in the Excel chart, but there is no reason obvious to me why that is so.

Comment: Oh, one important thing that might help: enable [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). Maybe there is something that setting would show that is hindering your progress with this.

Comment: The reason for the gap in the data is due to my dates. There is no data for two of the dates. Excel recognizes it VB.NET dont

Comment: Can you make a minimal program that shows the problem on an a computer with an internet connection?

Comment: I was able to get everything plotted as needed I had to change some of my code around but it worked! Now for some reason my chart area does not fill the screen how can this be changed?